# What are my options to run MS SQL 2012 on Amazon RDS for development if I only have MSDN license?

Tags: licensing, amazon-rds, sql-server-2012

I want to run MS SQL 2012 SE BYOL on Amazon RDS under my own MSDN license but it looks like MSDN license doesn't allow me to run MS SQL unless I host it on the dedicated hardware

> Microsoft Volume Licensing Product Use Rights (July 2014) states, “You
>   may install and use permitted copies of the software on Servers and
>   other devices that are under the day-to-day management and control of
>   third parties, provided all such Servers and other devices are and
>   remain fully dedicated to your use.”

http://aws.amazon.com/windows/resources/msdn/

So I need to know what my options are. I don't want to use EC2 Dedicated option for two reasons: too expensive and I don't want to install SQL server myself.

Comment: Greg, it's very specific question. I'm quite familiar with MS SQL licensing on prem but SQL-as-a-service especially with BYOL option is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Please call the Microsoft licensing.

1(866) 230-0560

MSDN license are bind too to the physical site where you are inscripted, thus you better have an official answer